# Both matchers fit, how to avoid filter being applied?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

This is my current security configuration; As you can see, I've got a `AntPathRequestMatcher` for `/api/**` that should apply a filter for token based security; My auth URL is under `/api/token` and should obviosly not be protected. The Current `.permitAll` seems to be ignored; How can I fix this?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")
    );

    private static final RequestMatcher FREE_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/token")
    );

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationProvider provider;

    public SecurityConfiguration(final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        super();
        this.provider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(FREE_URLS).permitAll()
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:
Here is my Filter: It could really be this "Throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException" but I dont know how to work arround this. Shouldn't it be possible by only changing the Filterchain Configuration? The Filter should only apply for those urls that are listed in PROTECTED_URLS except which got excluded by FREE_URLS. In case i'm changing the filter wouldn't it be needed to tell the Filter the FREE URLS then?

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    AuthenticationFilter(final RequestMatcher requiresAuth) {
        super(requiresAuth);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String token= httpServletRequest.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        if(token==null) throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Kein Token im Header angegeben");
        token = StringUtils.removeStart(token, "Bearer").trim();
        Authentication requestAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, token);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(requestAuthentication);

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain, final Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second call of `.authorizeRequests()` overrides the first one.

Comment: If I understand the linked post correctly it is not the same as my problem;

In my case all SECURED_URLS (A) Pathes are secured except FREE_URLS (B) but still set B is part of set A.

Comment: No you didn't understand it correctly. One problem is that you are using `authorizeRequests` twice. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: `new AuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS)` should only apply your filter for protected URLs, but `/api/**` contains `/api/token`. Hence your filter is also applied for free URLs. you have to exclude the free URLs.

Comment: You mean Excluding the URL from Protected URLS? 
So i would have to define Protected Urls as array containing {"/api/path1/**","/api/path2/**","/api/path3/**"} and not "/api/token"?

Comment: The easiest way is to change your implemenation of your filter to exclude the public URLs.

Comment: Thank you a Lot for your Input; I've implemented it now and it seems to work as expected. If it does something weird in future I'll come back to this Stack or create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by placing more specific configuration first so it matches first.

Change your configure method like following:

```
http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(FREE_URLS).permitAll()
        .and()
    .authenticationProvider(provider)
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(FREE_URLS).permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated()
        .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .formLogin().disable()
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .logout().disable();
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer; I've copied your suggestion to my code but sadly it does not work as expected.
The response still remains:
`{
  "timestamp": "2020-08-16T14:21:53.388+0000",
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "path": "/api/token"
}`